# Unable to read the session values in .Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing problem in handling session value in .Net MVC4 application. I am trying to create and assign User ID in session and trying to read it from another control(which is in different Area). But when I read the Session value, it's returning null value. Here is the code [Login Page]

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("school")]
public ActionResult school_post(string Code, string Password)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Validation Val = new Validation();
        if (Val.LoginAthenticated(Code, Password, 1))
        {
            Session["schoolcode"] = Code;
            Response.Redirect("school/dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Incorrect credentials')</script> ");
        }

    }
    return View();
}
```

And Dashboard Code:

```
public class dashboardController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /school/dashboard/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string test = Session["schoolcode"] as string;
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        return View(dashboard);
    }

}
```

Do I need to change anything in the above code or any application configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Session["schoolcode"]
       is having an integer value.Then it will return only null while you cast it using Session["schoolcode"] as string.

Try Session["schoolcode"].Tostring(). you will get your value

Comment: Its contain string. I have tried both .ToString() & Convert.ToString() but no use.

Comment: do you have this code  in ur web.config    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Inproc"
      timeout="20"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: I solved the issue. I replaced Response.Redirect("school/dashboard"); with return RedirectToAction("index", "dashboard", new { Area = "school" });   Thank you @DineshKumar